# simple example of native app passing string to website?

Tags: java, javascript, android, blackberry

Can somebody give a simple example for java code of a native app passing a string to a website?

For example: when a string has the value `Hello everybody`, the text `Hello everybody` should get pasted into the Google search field.

Comment: I think we could be more helpful if you described what you want to accomplish, not how to do it.

Comment: well simple as it is: i want string from my app be pasted into some website, after for example user fills  the field in my app

Answer (score 3):

For the most simple use, you can try:

```
public static void browseURL(Activity activity, String url)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        message(activity, "Sorry, failed to view the desired page.");
    }
}
```

and then call:

```
browseURL("http://www.google.com/search?q=Hello+World")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to fill the fields and submit them? If so, just do the request with the request parameters filled, and parse the response given by the server. Look into Apache HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to add text to the Google search field explicitly. You can send a URL with a query string.

Depending on the website the query string will always be different. For Google it is http://www.google.ca/search?q=something . Anything after a ? is considered a query string which any good web developer will include in a webpage. That query string takes custom commands in the form of ?command=query for command&command2=query for command 2.

Since this is tagged blackberry, I assume you want to implement a blackberry app, and you don't explicitly explain what you want to do, so you have two options,

1. [Invoke the browser](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/App-Integration-summary.html)

On that page it describes how to open a browser session. So within the

```
browserSession.displayPage("http://http://www.google.ca/search?q=searching%20for%20something");
```

If you need a class for URL encoding, let me know and I'll send one your way.

1. Http Request to pull the html of the webpage into the code. To do that, you'll have to look at my blog this week as I'll be posting a full in code network class either tomorrow or tuesday, which I'll edit this post to contain a link to.

OR you can send me a message if you need it NOW and I can email the non-cleaned up code to you.